# Клиенты Wireguard не видят сеть за сервером

Tags: маршрутизация, wireguard

Возможно ответ на этот вопрос уже есть, но я неделю капаю интернет и не могу найти нормального решения данной проблемы.

Есть сеть 10.51.5.0/24 в этой сети есть сервер Wireguard 10.51.5.204, шлюзом выступает mikrotik с адресом 10.51.5.1. Все хорошо работает. Клиенты vpn подключаются и видят друг друга. С любого компьютера сети пингуется любой клиент vpn. А вот клиенты vpn пингуют только сервер и шлюз. В чем проблема? на сервере net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1, на шлюзе маршрут в сеть vpn есть.

---

Трассировка показывает последний пункт это сервер впн

Comment: Смотрите трассировку, после какого узла сети начинают теряться пакеты

Comment: Согласен с @andreymal, подробнее изучите, что происходит с данными после отдельных частей, в  которых может возникать проблемы. И, если не справитесь сами, то сильно рекомендую прикрепить все замеры/данные, что могут помочь воспроизвести проблему.